# Adding Boost.Log to boost libraries using CMake

Tags: c++, logging, boost, cmake

I am trying to add `Boost.Log` to the Boost libraries using CMake, but I am having trouble when trying to link into my program.

I've added a wrapper around the `Boost.Log` and generated a shared library called `libcls_utils.so`. The Boost libraries (along with `Boost.Log`) appear to be built and generate all the `.so` files properly in the correct location, and so does `libcls_utils.so`.
When I try to link my file, I get the following error:

> /media/data/workspace/mdxdev/tmp/staging/i686-mv-linux/usr/lib/libcls_utils.so: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_file_backend::construct(boost::fil‌​esystem2::basic_path, std::allocator >, boost::filesystem2::path_traits> const&, std::_Ios_Openmode, unsigned long long, boost::function0 const&, bool)

As far as I can tell, I'm linking against all the correct libraries. Has anyone tried this before successfully? What am I doing wrong?
I am using CMake 2.8.8, Boost-1.49.0 and Boost.Log from the svn trunk.

Comment: What troubles are you encountering?

Comment: I've added a wrapper around the Boost.Log and generated a shared library called libcls_utils.so. The Boost libraries (along with Boost.Log) appear to be built and generate all the .so files properly in the correct location, so does my libcls_utils.so. When I try and link my file, I get:

Comment: /media/data/workspace/mdxdev/tmp/staging/i686-mv-linux/usr/lib/libcls_utils.so: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::sinks::basic_text_file_backend<char>::construct(boost::filesystem2::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem2::path_traits> const&, std::_Ios_Openmode, unsigned long long, boost::function0<bool> const&, bool)'
As far as I can tell I am linking against all the correct libraries.

Comment: It is important to note that boost log is not part of official boost library. So in cmake if you are using some boost specific macros, they wont expand to include boost log libs.

Comment: I suspect a mismatch in boost::filesystem API versions.  Boost 1.49 provides version 2, but defaults to 3.  Perhaps Boost.Log was built without any version override, meaning API version 3, and your wrapper library was built somehow defining BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define [BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html):

```
g++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK blog.cpp -lboost_log -lpthread
```